# Using a HashMap in Hibernate Many-to-Many mapping. Hibernate could not find mapKey

Tags: java, hibernate

Would it be possible to declare a HashMap in the following object called Group?

Doing something like this doesn't work:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group")
@MapKey(name = "member.name")
private Map<String, GroupMember> groupMembers = new HashMap<String, GroupMember>();
```

StackTrace:

```
12:07:51 [INFO] [Groups] Enabling Groups v0.1
12:07:51 [SEVERE] Error occurred while enabling Groups v0.1 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.RuntimeException: An exception has occured while initializing the database
        at groups.storage.MyDatabase.initializeDatabase(MyDatabase.java:83)
        at groups.storage.Dao.<init>(Dao.java:26)
        at groups.Groups.onEnable(Groups.java:30)
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:217)
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:457)
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:381)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.loadPlugin(CraftServer.java:282)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:264)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:605)
        at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:184)
        at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:23)
        at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:188)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:523)
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_5_R2.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:512)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.DedicatedServer.am(DedicatedServer.java:261)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.DedicatedServer.r(DedicatedServer.java:226)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.q(MinecraftServer.java:474)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:407)
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_5_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:573)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create a new instance of the EbeanServer
        at groups.storage.MyDatabase.loadDatabase(MyDatabase.java:162)
        at groups.storage.MyDatabase.initializeDatabase(MyDatabase.java:77)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: groups.model.Group: Could not find mapKey property [member.name] on [groups.model.GroupMember]
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanPropertyAssocMany.initMapKeyProperty(BeanPropertyAssocMany.java:744)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanPropertyAssocMany.initialise(BeanPropertyAssocMany.java:147)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptor.initialiseOther(BeanDescriptor.java:763)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.initialiseAll(BeanDescriptorManager.java:403)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:293)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:150)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:209)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:64)
        at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:78)
        at groups.storage.MyDatabase.loadDatabase(MyDatabase.java:159)
        ... 19 more
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups_group")
public class Group {

    public enum Type {
        Include,
        Exclude
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group")
    @MapKey(name = "member.name")
    private Map<String, GroupMember> groupMembers = new HashMap<String, GroupMember>();

    @Column(name = "personal", nullable = false)
    private Boolean personal = false;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private Type type = Type.Include;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = true, length = 16)
    private String password;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    Timestamp updatetime;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
    Timestamp createTime;

    public Group() {}

    //getters and setters
}
```

..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups_group_member")
public class GroupMember {

    public enum Role {
        ADMIN,
        MODERATOR,
        MEMBER,
        BANNED
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "member_id")
    private Member member;

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "role", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private Role role = Role.MEMBER;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    Timestamp updatetime;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
    Timestamp createTime;

    public GroupMember() {}

        //getters and setters...
}
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups_member")
public class Member {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 16)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "member")
    private Set<GroupMember> groupMembers = new HashSet<GroupMember>();

    @Version
    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false)
    Timestamp updatetime;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false)
    Timestamp createTime;

    public Member() {}

//getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be "name" instead of "member.name" ?

Comment: No, because as far as im aware, it's mapped through GroupMember. GroupMember doesn't have name, it only has Member. So I have to go member.name. Make sense?